# How to avoid multiple instances of a library entry class in a complex program in C++?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

Excuse the newbie question. I have a created a set of functions in multiple classes and wrapped these in a static library (used the Qt Creator's *staticlib* configuration). In a higher level program I am accessing the functionality by creating a new instance of the MyLibrary class as follows:

```
#include "mylibrary.h"
myLibrary *myLibrary;
myLibrary = new MyLibrary(); // new instance of the MyLibrary class (main entry)
myLibrary->initialize(); // initializes hardware properties
```

This is ok if I only need to access the library from one place in the program. However, I would like to handle several operations in multiple threads and I will be expanding the application to several new classes. The initialize() method configures hardware parameters which should only be done once at application launch. However, I wish to have access to all public methods of the library from any place in the application. I would like to achieve something like this:

```
main.cpp

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    MyLibrary::initialize(); // call the configuration method
    // Current issue: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    ...
}

classA.cpp

void doSomething()
{
    MyLibrary::setParameterA(0); // possible after initialization
}

classB.cpp

{
    MyLibrary::getParameterA(); // should return any value set by the user (for example "0" as above)
}
```

I have looked at possible solutions online and the most common suggestion I came across was to use the Singleton pattern inside the high-level application. Perhaps I could avoid that since I can still re-work the library at this stage. Could you suggest how to achieve that goal?

Comment: does `initialize` need access to members of `MyLibrary` ? From the code you posted it isnt clear why `initialize` cannot be static, or why it cannot be a free function.

Comment: This looks like an appropriate use case for a singleton. Just don't use "Meyer's" singleton and you'll be fine.

Comment: The singleton pattern can smoothly be implemented in C++. My advice is to stick to it...

Comment: The initialize method performs several actions by accessing various library members. If this is a valid singleton use-case, perhaps I could utilize it.

Comment: Why don't pass variable explicitly? Instead of having a "global" access: `void doSomething(MyLibrary& myLibrary) { myLibrary.setParameterA(0); /*..*/ }`

Comment: @user7860670 Why not use Meyer's singleton? It's thread-safe.

Comment: @jignatius Have you considered what it means for Meyer's singleton to be thread-safe? First of all it performs lazy initialization. This is a problem by itself because client code must be ready to deal with initialization failure (and a huge problem if you need to pass some arguments to constructor). In order to keep it thread safe compiler will emit a global lock at function entrance. Moreover, by using Meyer's singleton one gives up control over object lifetime. And later these people end up whining on the internet about singletons being bad for testing.

Comment: Hi all! A solution to my problem might be this: initialize the MyLibrary class with an std::unique_ptr in the main method of my application, then pass a pointer to any UI class initialized in main.

Answer (score 0):

Change *class* to *namespace*. Then no-one can instantiate multiple instances.

Your example usage also exactly fits for a namespace.